# How to host a dynamic html page in windows server

Tags: html, iis, windows-server-2008, vs-web-site-project

I am trying to host a dynamic html page that shows an updated value from a json file which resides in the same directory where the html page is hosted. I hosted the page through IIS with port number 8081 as new website and when I browse the page , it is not showing the updated value from the josn file.
If launch the page from the directory itself, it shows the updated values. 
Appreciate if anyone can help to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide your code sample so we can know what operation are you doing?

1.To enable static content .html,.json or client side dynamic script .js, we only need to ensure IIS  static content and feature has been installed for your IIS.
[image]

2.Please ensure your Application pool identity and authenticated user(IUSR) would have permission to access this file.

3.Since the symptom looks like a client side issue. Please try to clean browser cache and try to access the web page in other modern web browser like chrome.